# why I am not able to get data if input type="number"

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I am using ejs to extract data into a html file. I am not able to extract data when input `type="number"` and if I change it to input `type="text"` then I am getting data. please let me know what is wrong with input `type="number"`

```
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/product.css">
</head>

<body>
   <%- include('../includes/navigation.ejs') %>

    <main>
        <form class="product-form" action="/admin/<% if(editing){ %> edit-product <% } else { %> add-product <% } %>" method="POST">
            <div class="form-control">


            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" step="0.01" value="<% if(editing){ %> <%= product.price %> <% } %>">
            </div>

            <button class="btn" type="submit"><% if(editing) {%> Edit Product <% } else { %> Add Product <% } %></button>
        </form>
    </main>
<%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
```

When I give input `type="number"`, I should be able to extract the data into input box

Comment: Type `number` allows only numbers and a dot. Maybe `product.price` contains something more like a space or a comma? What's the schema for the product model?

Comment: that is because input type=number only take number. try to parse your price to integer and then it will show it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove space between EJS tags.

With space:

```
<input type="number" name="price" id="price" step="0.01" value="<% if (editing) { %> <%= product.price %> <% } %>">
```

Space removed:

```
<input type="number" name="price" id="price" step="0.01" value="<% if (editing) { %><%=product.price %><% } %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `" "` in  value attribute.

So, you can try this :

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" step="0.01" value=<% if(editing){ %> <%= product.price %> <% } %>>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey buddy i find the same problem i solved like this its all about spacing

```
//suppose u are just displaying like this e.g below
   <input type="number" name="cus_stateCode" placeholder="Enter StateCode" id="cus_stateCode" value="<%=foundItem.stateCode%> ">
```

this is how we normaly write what wrong in above e.g is the extra space in end between %> and "> if u remove this space like below e.g

```
   <input type="number" name="cus_stateCode" placeholder="Enter StateCode" id="cus_stateCode" value="<%=foundItem.stateCode%>">
```

we will able to see the desire result
i hope this example help you.

Answer (score -1):

> This because type="number" allows only numbers.

and may be product.price contains any non decimal value that's why data you are not getting data. So you should parse data into number.

try this :

```
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" step="0.01" value="<% if(editing){ %> <%= parseInt(product.price) %> <% } %>">
```